# Logic level mosfet wont drive solenoid

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, datasheet, solenoid, logic-level

I am trying to find out why my current mosfet is not working by looking over the datasheet. Ultimately I am just trying to buy a mosfet that I know will work, but I want to understand the datasheets fully before purchasing.
I am trying to drive a solenoid with a microcontroller and using the mosfet as a switch. The MC outputs 3.3 volts, and the solenoid is a 12V, 2 amp. Direct current. The mosfet is an RFP30N06LE. The MC goes high for 500ms then off. I have my circuit wired as below (ironically, this random picture even has the same mosfet as me)

[image]

I understand that a solenoid will require a flyback diode that is not shown. I do not currently have one, but I dont think that is the problem. In the datasheet here are the values I understand to be important to follow when sizing a mosfet.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Looking at the above data, it appears you need to apply a minimum of 1 volt to get the mosfet to begin opening. By 5 volts, the mosfet is fully open. I am applying 3.3 volts, so the mosfet is not fully open. However, according to the graph, a voltage of 3.3 to the gate allows for about 20 amps (albeit at 15 volts, not 12), which is more than my required 2. When I tried this in real life, I did not get a reaction from the solenoid at 3.3 volts. I then used an arduino 5 volt output to try and trigger the solenoid. Still nothing, but the mosfet got very hot. Finally, I applied 12 volts to the mosfet gate (above the MFG 10 volt maximum) and the solenoid opened.

What am i missing? Since this mosfet doesn't work, I want to get the Nexperia PMV28UNEA instead. It has a VGS of 0.45V - 1V (smaller), and an RDSon of 3.9 amps at 2.5V (I need 2 amps at 3.3V). I want to make sure I understand things before I buy it though.

Comment: Your belief that you don't need the diode is *severely* mistaken, as without it you are likely to permanently damage the MOSFET if you have not done so already - a probability strongly suggested by the MOSFET getting hot.  As for debugging, get out your meter.  What voltage do you measure gate to source?  What do you measure drain to source?  What do your measure across the coil of the solenoid?  Edit these facts into the question itself.

Comment: `I then used an arduino 5 volt output to try and trigger the solenoid. Still nothing, but the mosfet got very hot.` This means that the MOSFET tried to get turned on but unfortunately it couldn't decrease its DS resistance. Since the DS resistance remained high and a non-zero current flew through, the I²R dissipation thus the heat was high. `Finally, I applied 12 volts to the mosfet gate (above the MFG 10 volt maximum) and the solenoid opened.` Probably the MOSFET is nearly dead because of the lack of a flyback (a.k.a. freewheeling) diode. Sorry for your loss.

Comment: The flyback diode is shown and it is needed and your MOSFET is now broken.

Comment: I do understand I ultimately need the diode, my point is that it will not engage, period. From my understanding, the diode is to prevent voltage kickback from the solenoid quickly returning to its base position. The solenoid is never engaged in the first place. The mosfet is not damaged, as I checked with a multimeter. I could check the values, and I appreciate the answer, however, if the specs as shown in this question indicate that it should work with the MC and solenoid as wired above, than thats enough to me to mean its simply a dud mosfet. I'd just like to confirm that it should work

Comment: I see multiple comments about including a diode. And i do see it is included in the diagram. Fair enough. So do these specs indicate that I do have the correct mosfet for this application? That simply including the dioide means it will now work, and not having the dioide is the only reason its not working?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the driving circuit. If you hooked it up as shown in the diagram then it should work without any problems. It's obvious that the main cause is the MOSFET: Either it is broken or it has not the specs shown in the datasheet. As I stated in my comment, it appears that even 5V is not enough to turn it on (The MOSFET could not decrease the Rds). Maybe you should try with a fresh new one.

Comment: Thank you. I swapped out and tried multiple mosfets of the same model, and still nothing.

Comment: Could you add a picture of your setup?

Comment: When you apply the 5 volts from your Arduino supply, measure the voltage between the source and the gate directly to make sure your grounds are good.